# Does cattell's profile similarity coefficient (Rp) exist as a function in R?

Tags: r

i'm comparing different measures of distance and similarity for vector profiles (Subtest results) in R, most of them are easy to compute and/or exist in dist(). 
Unfortunately, one that might be interesting and is to difficult for me to calculate myself is *Cattel's Rp*. I can not find it in R.
Does anybody know if this exists already?
Or can you help me to write a function?

The formula (Cattell 1994) of Rp is this:

```
(2k-d^2)/(2k + d^2)
```

where:

k is the median for chi square on a sample of size n;

d is the sum of the (weighted=m) difference between the two profiles, 
sth like: `sum(m(x(i)-y(i)))`;

one thing i don't know is, how to get the chi square median in there

Thank you

What i get without defining the k is:

```
Rp.Cattell <- function(x,y){z <- (2k-(sum(x-y))^2)/(2k+(sum(x-y))^2);return(z)}
```

Vector examples are:

```
x <- c(-1.2357,-1.1999,-1.4727,-0.3915,-0.2547,-0.4758)

y <- c(0.7785,0.9357,0.7165,-0.6067,-0.4668,-0.5925)
```

They are measures by the same device, but related to different bodyparts. They don't need to be standartised or weighted, i would say.

Comment: What is your approach?

Comment: Shouldn't be too hard to code... can you show what you've got so far?

Comment: Hi Khashaa, sorry, what do you mean with approach? The resaerch question is to find a good way to quantify performance differences in subjects over two testtimes, and use this for between subject comparison in relation to another performance measure...

Comment: Hi Dominic, i havn#t got anything else than the functions i showed, since i hoped to find a ready made function. It might be true though - what i mentioned so far is not difficult except the chi square ...

Comment: A search on RSeek.org gives 0 results, so it's quite possible it's not out there (yet). Can you give an example of inputs for the function? (2 straight vectors? Or structures having other classes?)

Answer (score 1):

[This page](http://blogs.sas.com/content/iml/2011/11/09/on-the-median-of-the-chi-square-distribution/) gives a general formula for k, and then gives a more thorough method using `SAS/IML` which pretty much gives the same results. So I used the general formula, added calculation of degrees of freedom, which leads to this:

```
Rp.Cattell <- function(x,y) { 
    dof <- (2-1) * (length(y)-1)
    k <- (1-2/(9*dof))^3
    z <- (2*k-sum(sum(x-y))^2)/(2*k+sum(sum(x-y))^2)
    return(z)
}

x <- c(-1.2357,-1.1999,-1.4727,-0.3915,-0.2547,-0.4758)
y <- c(0.7785,0.9357,0.7165,-0.6067,-0.4668,-0.5925)

Rp.Cattell(x, y)

# [1] -0.9012083
```

Does this figure appear to make sense?

Comment: Thank you!  meanwhile i changed the main function  - it was differently written down in the original paper and another one quoting it, i will have to find out about this.  Approximating - 1 means very dissimilar profiles, thatseems possible...  <br/> Quantifying profile similarity is quite difficult, so i'm happy to have been coming a bit closer to this now. Thanks again

Comment: Sure np, & pls update us when you've got this figured out, so we can make a more definitive answer!

Answer (score 0):

Trying to verify the function, I found out now that the median of chisquare is the chisquare value for 50% probability - relating to random. So the function should be:

```
Rp.Cattell <- function(x,y){
    dof <- (2-1) * (length(y)-1)
      k <- qchisq(.50, df=dof)
      z <- (2k-(sum(x-y))^2)/(2k+(sum(x-y))^2);
      return(z)}
```

It is necessary though to standardize the Values before, so the results are distributed correctly.

So:

```
library ("stringr")

# they are centered already    
x <- as.vector(scale(c(-1.2357,-1.1999,-1.4727,-0.3915,-0.2547,-0.4758),center=F, scale=T)) 

y <- as.vector(scale(c(0.7785,0.9357,0.7165,-0.6067,-0.4668,-0.5925),center=F, scale=T))

Rp.Cattell(x, y)  -0.584423
```

This sounds reasonable now - or not?

Comment: As I can see, both answers are incorrect, to my mind, according to the original source paper. First, standardization of values must be not within the profiles, but within the dimensions. Second, df=n (length of profile), not n-1. D^2 in the coefficient formula is the sq. euclidean distance (could be weighted one) between the two profiles.

Answer (score 0):

I consider calculation of z is incorrect.

You need to calculate the sum of the squared differences. Not the square of the sum of differences. Besides product operator is missing in 2k.

It should be

```
z <- (2*k-sum((x-y)^2))/(2*k+sum((x-y)^2))
```

Do you agree?